# git-dir not working as path is not recognized

Tags: git

I want to use an automated push script using git and configured my post-receive hook:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read oldrev newrev ref
do
        if [[ $ref =~ .*/master$ ]];
        then
                echo "Master ref received. Deploying master branch to production server..."
                git --work-tree=/var/www/MFDispo --git-dir=~/Documents/MFDispo/.git checkout -f
        else
                echo "Ref $ref successfully received. Doing nothing. Only the master branch may be deployed on this server."
        fi
done
```

But the push is not working:

```
remote: Master ref received. Deploying master branch to production server...
remote: fatal: Not a git repository: '~/Documents/MFDispo/.git'
```

But the folder on my client contains the git repo. I see the folder within the folder structure and the git system is working as I use it throughout coding and committing.

Do I need to specify the path differently?

**UPDATE**

After changing the path for `--git-dir` to `$HOME/Documents...` the same error appears but I can see the path he is searching in now as well. It is `/home/sesc/Documents...`. But this is on my production server. I thought on the client the path is being searched by entering the path in the file?

**UPDATE 2**
So now I tried the following:

1. Cloning the repository on my production server initially
2. Changing --git-dir to: `var/www/MFDispo` (this is the path on the production server)
3. Starting the same script again

Now I get the error:
`remote: error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database objects`

do I need to `chmod` the folder before I can start? At least it seems better than before!

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

`~` only expands to your home directory when it's at the beginning of a shell word (roughly, when it's at the beginning of the line or preceded by whitespace).  Thus, in `--git-dir=~/Documents/MFDispo/.git`, the `~` is not expanded, and so Git looks for a directory literally named `~`, which (I assume) doesn't exist.  You have either write out the path to your home directory in full or else replace it with the shell variable `$HOME`:

```
--git-dir=$HOME/Documents/MFDispo/.git
```

Comment: I changed the line of code therefore. But when using the $HOME variable I found out, that the path he is spitting out now is: /home/sesc/Documents... This /home/sesc is on my production server. So why does he search there and not locally?

Comment: @sesc360: Because post-receive hooks are executed on the server that the code was pushed to, not the server that it was pushed from.

Comment: oh... So I think I misunderstood the concept then. So what does it mean now for me: I need to initally clone the code to my production server and change the code to the git folder on my production?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the ~ prefix is being expanded appropriately in the context where you are using it; it is expanded by bash only when bash recognizes it as the start of a word, not in the middle of an argument.

Try substituting ${HOME} instead on the relevant line:

```
            git --work-tree=/var/www/MFDispo --git-dir=${HOME}/Documents/MFDispo/.git checkout -f
```